# How to get Swift KVO working for static member?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, key-value-observing

I have a UIViewController with the following code. I want to know when the value of portrait effect is changed (in control center). I have tried `AVCaptureDevice.isPortraitEffectEnabled` and `.portraitEffectEnabled`, both have the same result: `observeValue()` is never called. I have verified that the value itself does actually change, and the docs state that KVO is supported for this member.

What am I missing?

To test this I am toggling the value of `portaitEffectEnabled` by calling `AVCaptureDevice.showSystemUserInterface(.videoEffects)` and turning it on/off, and expecting the KVO to fire.

```
@objc class EventSettingsCaptureViewController : UIViewController, ... {

    required init(...) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            AVCaptureDevice.self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "portraitEffectEnabled", options: [.new], context: nil)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            AVCaptureDevice.self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "portraitEffectEnabled", context: nil)
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        // Breakpoint set here: never hits
        if keyPath == "portraitEffectEnabled" {
            guard let object = object as? AVCaptureDevice.Type else { return }

            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                WLog("isPortraitEffectEnabled changed: \(object.isPortraitEffectEnabled)")
            }

        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won’t work because `AVCaptureDevice` itself doesn’t have a `portraitEffectSupported` property. _Instances_ of `AVCaptureDevice` do, because it’s an instance property. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceformat/3875312-portraiteffectsupported?language=objc

Comment: By the way, you can always use `class_copyPropertyList` to double check that the property you’re trying to observe actually exists on that object.  You can initialize an unsafe buffer pointer from that, then map over it to get the names of all the properties, to see if the one you want is there

Comment: Please note that there is no such thing as "Swift KVO". KVO is a Cocoa / Objective-C feature. The `observeValue` method _wraps_ Cocoa KVO, but it doesn't do anything of itself. The way Swift observes a value is with setter observer, Combine and Published, etc.

Comment: UGH thanks @Alexander - can't believe I missed this. I'd accept it as the answer if you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won’t work because the `AVCaptureDevice` class itself doesn’t have a `portraitEffectSupported` property.

The issue is that the [`portraitEffectSupported` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceformat/3875312-portraiteffectsupported?language=objc) is an *instance* property.

you can always use `class_copyPropertyList` to double check that the property you’re trying to observe actually exists on that object. Here's an example:

```swift
import AVFoundation

func getPropertyNames(of target: AnyObject) -> [String] {
    let itsClass: AnyClass = object_getClass(target)!
    
    var count = UInt32()
    guard let p = class_copyPropertyList(itsClass, &count) else {
        return []
    }

    defer { p.deallocate() }
    
    let properties = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: p, count: Int(count))
    
    return properties.map { String(cString: property_getName($0)) }
}

// `AVCaptureDevice` has no class properties.
let propertiesOfTheClassItself = getPropertyNames(of: AVCaptureDevice.self)
print(propertiesOfTheClassItself) // => []

// Instances of `AVCaptureDevice` have some instance properties.
let propertiesOfASampleInstance = getPropertyNames(of: AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)!)
print(propertiesOfASampleInstance) // => ["transportControlsSupported", "transportControlsPlaybackMode", "transportControlsSpeed", "adjustingFocus", "adjustingExposure", "adjustingWhiteBalance"]
```